# access O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, ... from nodejs

Tags: node.js, operating-system, constants

Is it possible to access the values of the OS constants `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, `O_APPEND` and such from nodejs?

I know they aren't the same in all platforms so the correct way would be to use the constants instead of relying in hardcoded values from my current system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can load the built-in `constants` module with `require('constants')` which will return an object containing the constants shown [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/9cbfd6ef51899dd869a8ec809766cf06d14c9a36/src/node_constants.cc). Example:

```
var consts = require('constants');
console.log(consts.O_RDONLY);
```

Comment: Great thank you. I don't feel very good using it because I can't find documentation online about it so it seems like an internal api that may change, but that's better than hardcoding values in my node code.

Comment: I doubt it will change because the other built-in modules in javascript land use it. My guess is that it's not documented because it exposes platform-specific bits.